# Using material-ui <Hidden> API causing bugs with React Lifecycle method

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

i am facing some bugs when using material-ui Hidden API with React Lifecycle method.

[Hidden API](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/api/hidden/)

Background:
i am building a blog using React, Next, Cosmic. 
Post contents from cosmicJS are inserted via dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

In order to style the components from CosmicJS

```
componentDidMount() {
const imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('fr-fic');
Array.from(imgs).map( img => {
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = 'auto';
});
const videos = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
Array.from(videos).map((video) => {
  video.style.position = 'relative';
  video.style.top = 0;
  video.style.left = 0;
  video.style.width = '100%';
  video.style.height = 360;
});
```

Then Hidden API was used to make a responsive page. And for some reason, Hidden API is causing issues with the styling of components via componentDidMount(). 
In my case, upon end of blog post (end of page), a new post will be rendered. Its only when the new post is rendered that the above styling will take effect.

```
<Hidden mdUp>
  <div className={this.classes.mobilepost_content} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.renderMarkup(this.articleContent)} />
</Hidden>
<Hidden smDown>
  <div className={this.classes.deskpost_content} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.renderMarkup(this.articleContent)} />
</Hidden>
```

Any advice on this?